# Drag & Drop in KListWidget (PyQt/PyKde programming)

Tags: drag-and-drop, pyqt, pykde, plasmoid

I'm developing a little app (precisely it's a KDE4 plasmoid) in PyQt/PyKde.

In my app I have a KListWidget filled with some rows, see this picture:

http://img212.imageshack.us/img212/8444/sshot3.jpg

I need to implement a drag&drop action for the list rows, for example I should be able to put any file over a row, then the app will send this file to the name on the list.

The list has been created by this snippet of code:

```
self.contactsList = KListWidget()
self.contactsList.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
self.contactsList.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
self.contactsList.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35));
```

Method to call when drag&drop happens is already implemented, I need only to connect the method to the list in a way similar to:

```
self.connect(self.contactsList, SIGNAL("signal_()"), self.method)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly has already been implemented? Also, what method do you want to "connect" to the list? Do you mean a Qt signal/slot connection?

Answer (score 0):

PyQt signals can be defined dynamically, so as long as the class that defines self.contacts_list_method() inherits from QWidget, it can emit a dynamic signal.

For example, at the end of the method in the contactsList object that handles your list appending code:

```
def contacts_list_method(self, someparameters):
  doStuff()
  doMoreStuff()
  ...
  self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("contacts_list_method_done()"))
```

Then in the initializer of the class that holds the contactsList object (or wherever you feel is a better place) put the following connection:

```
self.connect(self.contactsList, SIGNAL("contacts_list_method_done()"), self.method)
```

You could also predefine the QtCore.SIGNAL("contacts_list_method_done()") as an object and then just refer to the object when you emit it in contacts_list_method.

Comment: this way does not work, but I've solved using a qtreewidget instead of the klistw

Comment: You should post what you actually did as an answer and select it as the correct answer (unless it's company confidential code obviously) so everyone can benefit. I imagine many people will want the behaviour you described at some point :)